# How to visualize a graph data structure?

Tags: plot, graph, erlang

I'm looking for a way to plot or visualize a graph made in Erlang using the `digraph` module. In the manual pages I can't find any function for doing this.

How do I plot or visualize a graph?

Answer (score 1):

For desktop application, pure `wx` is one choice.

[wx graph] [1]https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/wxgraphicspath

I think you have to write many program for developing your necessary api because `wx`'s api not enough.

I have used `wx` just before, erlang's `wx` is not active. It's document's and Q&A is not enough, Time cost is high.

Another choice may be to use `wx` + `webview`, send the data to javascript to show graph by it.

It save your save to develop above mentioned necessary api.

Third choice may be to use `dart/flutter` as client, erlang as server to send data. In this choice, no need  `wx`.